# JSON array from Database query

Tags: php, javascript, sql-server, ajax

I want to query data from a database into a json array that ultimalty produces a force directed graph in javascript. Here is what the Json array should look like in the end result. However nodes can have mulitiple adjacencies or none, how can I query a json array where the adjacencies section varies from node to node and is able to adjust according to the number of adjacencies a node has?

```
Var JSON =[ 
 {
  "adjacencies": [
    {
      "nodeTo": "graphnode9", 
      "nodeFrom": "graphnode5", 
      "data": {}
    }
  ], 
  "data": {
    "$color": "#416D9C", 
    "$type": "star"
  }, 
  "id": "graphnode5", 
  "name": "graphnode5"
},
];
```

Here is my attempt so far, however this only produces a json that only allows one adjacencies, How can I setup a Json query that will adjust the the number of adjacencies a node has and not limit itself to just one set array form or array structure?

Here is my Database structure

```
nodes                 Relationships                      
-----                 -------------
id int(11),           id int(11),
name varchar(35),     to int(11), //this is the destination node from the id relation 
color varchar(7),     data varchar(0) null
type varchar (12),    Foreign key (id) references nodes(id)
Primary key (id)       

engine = innodb
```

And here is my attempt that

```
function getjson()
{
 $db = adodbConnect();
 $query = "SELECT nodes.*, relationships.* FROM nodes LEFT JOIN relationships ON nodes.id    = relationships.id";
 $result = $db -> Execute($query);
 $count=$result->RowCount();
 $row=$result->FetchRow();

 $array= array[];

 while ($row)
  {
  $id= $row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $color1 = $row['color'];
  $type1 = $row['type'];
  $to=$row['to'];
  $array = [$id,$name,$color1,$type1,$to];
 }
 json_encode($array)
 }
```

Comment: Never, NEVER, try to produce json output by hand. There is `json_encode`, a built-in function that just do it. With one correction - do it correctly, efficiently and being aware of multiple nested level arrays, objects and whole lot of other stuff you might want to send to JSON. Aside from that, how do you expect to turn your database data into a graph? So, there are actually two parts in your question. Unfortunately, the hard one can't be solved not knowing your database structure. Please post it. Also, why there are `top 1` in the query?

Comment: Why are you creating the JSON yourself and do not rely on PHP to do so?  Just create your object in PHP and then use `json_encode`

Comment: Hi JOHN I updated my question with the database and extra info, thank you so much for your help.